# Complex find, lookup & import range of data/cells

Tags: google-sheets, match, dropdown, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm asking about the best way to filter, import, lookup, the data from a sheet looking like that. 
that's a finale datasheet to import multiple room types with all its prices, from different hotels, from different sheet. see the image below,

- First column has a Hotel code(no duplication)
- then it can have 1~12 rooms (name of room under the Room 1/2/3) can be duplicate
- then you will see in the sheet the breakdown of prices for adult children and so on for each room.

Now I'm stuck for a couple of days for a method to filter and import only the criteria I'm looking for.

- first it must bring the hotel range (because of multiple hotels on 1 sheet)
- then select the room and import the prices belong to it,
- then find the prices for the specific date entered.  the last part is the easy 1 with just a vlooup. I'm stuck in the structure of begging.

Here's a copy of sheet, Editable and photo of the copied range

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UMKSJ43wByqnCzzZZY9qbzoL9rD0rH8A4_sF0djWpLI/edit?usp=sharing

[image: Screenshot]

The required search filters are in Sheet ('Tools')

Comment: @ScottCraner Google Spreadsheet

Comment: Anybody can help ?? i'm going seriously crazy here

Comment: i cannot use index in lookups because columns changes, i cannot use hlookups coz not all the columns all rows have the value i'm looking for, i cannot figure out the import range based on specific cell and import the range that belong to that cell, i cannot figure out a way to import the dynamic range of cells and rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can solve this by using side columns to calculate items for dropdown for example like this:

[image: 0]

Comment: You are the best, after the edits you made, everything is perfect, cannot thank you enough for your help really